# How to pass a variable from BeforeTest to Test annotation

Tags: java, annotations, testng

I am trying to read data from excel in @BeforeTest method and trying to print same in @Test method in testNG. I have read the data in a sheet

```
@BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"filePath", "fileName", "sheetName"})
    public void readExcel(String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName) throws IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException{
        // set the file path
        File eFile = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
        //print the file path
        System.out.println("File is at: "+eFile);

        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(eFile);

        // Read and publish extension
        String extensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        System.out.println("File type is: "+extensionName);

        //Read the file
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);

        //Read the sheet name
        Sheet wbSheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

    }
```

I would like to pass the wbSheet to @Test method to print and write data to excel. @Parameters is looking for constant defined in testng.xml. How to pass a variable like this..?

Comment: What about object variable, i.e. field in test class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use an instance variable?

```
class YourClassTest {

  Sheet wbSheet;

  @BeforeTest public void readExcel(...) {
    wbSheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
  }

  @Test public void test() {
    //you can use wbSheet here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any variable decalared and defined in @BeforeTest can be used in @Test I guess.
Please correct me if I am wrong.
Example below that worked for me:

```
@BeforeTest
public void getUrl(){

    RestAssured.baseURI = envProp.getProperty("HOST_GET");

}

@Test
public void listUsers() {

given().when().get("/maps/...").then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
}
}
```